# Nx NextJS Runtime config variables are "undefined" while running production build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nrwl, nrwl-nx

Nextjs app that is created via Nx Nextjs schematics gives **undefined** for `publicRuntimeConfig` accessed in `getInitialProps` during runtime of production build but in `development` mode it works perfectly

next.config.js:

```
module.exports = { 
   serverRuntimeConfig: { // Will only be available on the server side 
      mySecret: 'secret', 
      secondSecret: process.env.SECOND_SECRET // Pass through env variables
   }, 
   publicRuntimeConfig: { // Will be available on both server and client 
      staticFolder: '/static' 
   } 
};
```

getInitialProps:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config'; 
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig(); 
... 
Index.getInitialProps = async ctx => { 
    console.log('I am here'); 
    console.log(publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder); // Undefined when 
    running prod build return {}; 
};
```

Orignal Github Issue [Here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2572)